# Escape JS and PHP blocks for Smarty 2

Tags: javascript, php, cs-cart, smarty2

Later Edit: This issue has been fixed. It seems that the problem was with a misplaced hook.

What is the right and best way to escape the JavaScript and PHP blocks in Smarty 2?

I have tried to:

- change every JS {} with {ldelim} respectiely {rdelim};
- add {literal} before  and {/literal} after
- add {php}phpcodehere{/php}

None of them seem to work.

Here is my code that needs to be escaped:

```
<script>
    var _ra = _ra || {};
    _ra.sendProductInfo = {
        "id": "{$product.product_id}",
        "name": "{$product.product}",
        "url": "{$config.current_url|fn_url}",
        "img": "{$product.main_pair.detailed.image_path}",
        {if $ra_oldPrice == $product.price or not is_numeric($ra_oldPrice)}
        "price": "{if $product.list_price > $product.price}{$product.list_price}{else}{$product.price}{/if}",
        "promo": "{if $product.list_price > $product.price}{$product.price}{else}0{/if}",
        {else}
        "price": "{$ra_oldPrice}",
        "promo": "{$product.price}",
        {/if}
        "brand": false,
        "category": [{
            "id": "{$catid}",
            "name": "{$product.main_category|fn_get_category_name}",
            "parent": false,
            "breadcrumb": []
        }],
        "inventory": {
            "variations": false,
            "stock": "{$product_amount = $product.inventory_amount|default:$product.amount}{if ($product_amount <= 0 || $product_amount < $product.min_qty) && $settings.General.inventory_tracking == "Y"}0{else}1{/if}"   
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: JS must not escaped see: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl#id2807434

Comment: PHP works fine with {php}phpcodehere{/php}, see http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl#id2807119   Look herer: Example 7.29   And try not to nesting rekursive to avoid buggy behavior.

Comment: The {} of JavaScript must be changed with {ldelim} respectively {rdelim} and I said I have already done that and it doesn't work :).

Comment: Does in not work when you do `change every JS {} with {ldelim} respectiely {rdelim};` only, on that code that is shown here?

Comment: Thing you should show the code of the changes too, not only the original.

Comment: Ok. Let's take the following code for example. What is wrong about it?

https://jsfiddle.net/zsk3r5db/

Comment: Checked  jsfiddle.net/zsk3r5db and as you can read here http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl within `{php}{/php}` you have to write normal php. so this `{php}{if $product.list_price > $product.price}{$product.list_price}{else}{$product.price}{/if}{/php}` should look llike this `{php}if ($product.list_price > $product.price) print $product.list_price; else print $product.price;{/php}`

Comment: Also this `{php}{$config.current_url|fn_url}{/php}` must be done in this way: `{$config.current_url|fn_url}` without the `{php}{/php}` because you dont do any php there

Comment: Is `fn_url` a `smarty_function_fn_url` function?

Comment: OK, im not sure about `{php}{$config.current_url|fn_url}{/php}`, but please read the doc from smarty http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/ and devlop&debug step by step

Comment: I've read the whole documentation through and through. I can't get this script to work. Thanks for your help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<script data-no-defer> 
    var _ra = _ra || {$ldelim}{$rdelim};
    _ra.sendProductInfo = {$ldelim}
        id: {$product.product_id},
        name: '{$product.product|escape:'javascript'}',
        url: '{$config.current_url|fn_url}',
        img: '{$product.main_pair.detailed.image_path}',
        {if $ra_oldPrice == $product.price or not is_numeric($ra_oldPrice)}
        price: {if $product.list_price > $product.price}{$product.list_price}{else}{$product.price}{/if},
        promo: {if $product.list_price > $product.price}{$product.price}{else}0{/if},
        {else}
        price: {$ra_oldPrice},
        promo: {$product.price},
        {/if}
        brand: false,
        category: [{$ldelim}
            id: {$product.main_category},
            name : '{$category_name=$product.main_category|fn_get_category_name}{$category_name|escape:'javascript'}',
            parent: false,
            breadcrumb: []
        {$rdelim}],
        inventory: {$ldelim}
            variations: false,
            stock: {$product_amount = $product.inventory_amount|default:$product.amount}{if ($product_amount <= 0 || $product_amount < $product.min_qty) && $settings.General.inventory_tracking == "Y"}0{else}1{/if}   
        {$rdelim}
    {$rdelim};
</script>
```

- the only variable I don't know is `$ra_oldPrice` but I guess is assigned above by you